# tty всегда в RAM

Tags: linux

В случае зависания системы (например при активном использовании swap раздела) приходится подолгу ждать переключения в tty (ctrl+alt+fN). Как можно запретить перемещать процесс tty в swap? Или каким образом можно быстро починить зависшую систему?

Comment: есть такая штука, как [magic sysrq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) — «прямая линия» с программой *linux*. посмотрите, какие команды можно передать — возможно, какая-то из них подойдёт вам вместо того, что вы хотите вводить в виртуальном терминале (то, что вы назвали «tty»).

Answer (score 1):

Быстро починить - это убить процесс жрущий ресурсы. Например через SysRq - 
прописываем в /etc/sysctl.conf

```
kernel.sysrq = 1
```

или без перезагрузки `sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1`

Теперь убить 1 самое активное приложение по мнению OOM достаточно один раз нажать

```
Alt+PrntSrc+F
```

Есть опасность, не известно, какое приложение  ООМ решит убить, это может быть и вкладка в браузере - где обновилась вкладка с множеством медиа банеров, плеером или музыкой, а может и графический интерфейс. Ещё одно нажатие , запустит ООМ ещё раз, и так далее пока не прибьётся всё )

По поводу запрета свопирования для конкретного процесса, думаю тут только играться с приоритетами, например как советуют тут: https://superuser.com/questions/243357/how-to-prevent-a-specific-program-from-swapping